# Android app/activity disposes when switching to another app

Tags: android

I've been asked to fix an android application which has issues after switching to a newer device. The switch was from android 7/8 to 11. The application opens up google maps for navigation but very often when returned to the app all data is lost, and clicking on anything will reset it back to the startup activity. It doesn't matter which apps it switches between the issue happens with all of them.

I've tried several things:

-Disabling all battery saving options on the device

-Using OnSaveInstanceState to retain the data

-Using a backgroundservice to retain the data

The issue only occurs on actual devices, using an emulator results in no errors.

When the debugger is attached to the application it loses its connection before returning to the app. It is possible to re-attach when returning to the app but it disconnects as soon as
anything is clicked.

And best of all there's literally no error message shown anywhere.

Comment: Your process can be terminated at any point when it is in the background. This is not new to Android 11. How aggressive the device is, in terms of terminating background processes, varies based on manufacturer, available RAM, what other apps are installed, etc. "And best of all there's literally no error message shown anywhere" -- that is because there is no error. See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#Processes) and [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle) for more.

Comment: Ahh I see. I read through it a bit and it makes sense. I'm having trouble finding something to keep it alive longer however, is that even possible? I saw something about a foreground service/broadcaster.

Comment: Ideally, you would let your process be destroyed, to free up system RAM.

Comment: Is there any way around this? the original creator of the application didn't exactly follow standard android guidelines/procedures. However rebuilding is not the preferred option (even though that would be better).

Comment: You would need to start a foreground service, complete with its `Notification`. Even that does not guarantee that your process will remain around.

Comment: I'm giving that a try, thanks for all the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following comment provided the solution I needed.

You would need to start a foreground service, complete with its Notification. Even that does not guarantee that your process will remain around.
– CommonsWare Sep 1 at 12:40